# How to retire a physical standby in Oracle 11.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dataguard

I have a production Oracle 11gR2 RAC database with a single node physical standby. Now it has become the time to retire the old standby and pass that role to a RAC on fresher hardware.

We don't use Data Guard Broker.

I haven't been able to find much on this particular process, so I figured maybe there wasn't all that much to it. Apparently there is at least a tad more than I have been able to think of.

After stopping the log apply on the old standby, I attempted to simply clear the standby log destination and set a new destination for log shipping. Oracle then complains that the DB_UNQUE_NAME of the new physical standby is not a part of the current Data Guard configuration.

```
SQL> alter system set log_archive_dest_3='';

System altered.

SQL> alter system checkpoint;

System altered.

SQL> alter system set log_archive_dest_3='SERVICE=PDB10SBY LGWR ASYNC REGISTER VALID_FOR=(online_logfile,primary_role) REOPEN=60 DB_UNIQUE_NAME=PDB11SBY' scope=both sid='*';
alter system set log_archive_dest_3='SERVICE=PDB10SBY LGWR ASYNC REGISTER VALID_FOR=(online_logfile,primary_role) REOPEN=60 DB_UNIQUE_NAME=PDB10SBY' scope=both sid='*'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because specified value is invalid
ORA-16053: DB_UNIQUE_NAME PDB10SBY is not in the Data Guard Configuration
```

A quick query to v$dataguard_config confirms that there is an active configuration containing the DB_UNIQUE_NAME of the old standby database.

```
SQL> select * from
  2  v$dataguard_config;

DB_UNIQUE_NAME
------------------------------
PDB10
PDB10_STBY
```

So then the question is, what are the steps required to retire an existing Data Guard configuration so that a new physical standby database can be deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique names of the databases in a Data Guard configuration are listed in the log_archive_config parameter in the following form:

```
log_archive_config='DG_CONFIG=(PDB10,PDB10_STBY)'
```

You can remove the old one and add the new one as:

```
alter system set log_archive_config='DG_CONFIG=(PDB10,PDB10SBY)';
```

After this, you can set log_archive_dest_N to the new standby.

Comment: Ah, there's Oracle for you. Hiding stuff away in inconsistent naming conventions where honest working folk won't easily find it. Worked like a charm!